# Ajax and JSONP Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I'm trying to fetch the data from host on 000webhost

the data is a JSONP file:

```
{
  "categories": {
    "category": [
      {
       "name": "Android",
       "parent": "Computer Science",
       "ID": "2323"
      },
      {
      "name": "Java",
      "parent": "Android",
      "ID": "12"
      },
      {
      "name": "HTML",
      "parent": "Android",
      "ID": "32"
      },
      {
      "name": "Javascript",
      "parent": "Android",
      "ID": "4552"
      },
      {
      "name": "CSS",
      "parent": "Android",
      "ID": "4553"
      },
      {
      "name": "Math",
      "parent": "Computer Science",
      "ID": "3778342"
      },
      {
      "name": "JAVA",
      "parent": "Computer Science",
      "ID": "377655"
      },
      {
      "name": "Computer Science",
      "parent": "none",
      "ID": "1"
      }
     ]
  }
}
```

I've tried:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

(mainFunction=function(){

$.ajax({

 dataType: 'jsonp',

 data: null,

 jsonp: 'categories',

 url: 'http://blabla.site11.com',

 success: function (response) {


 }
  });

})();
```

but I always get the error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token.

I just wan't to know how can I fetch the categories.jsonp file from http://blabla.site11.com/categories.jsonp

Comment: Sound like server doesn't handle jsonp

Comment: You know, that JSONP requires the server to add a JS function call around the JSON ?

Answer (score 0):

Your server must return this:

```
categories('<your JSON>');
```

In your client code, you must have a `categories()` function that does the processing of that JSON (it must accept it as an argument). If your server does not do that, you are adding an script to your page that contains only JSON, which causes a syntax error.

So, either your server handles the JSON natively, or you'll have to modify the contents of your file so it complies with a JSONP valid request.